# Pointer wrapper for insertion

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Can someone tell me if there is a datatype in C++/STL that allows me to solve the following problem comfortably:

- I have a preallocated contiguous area of memory representing an array of objects of type T.
- I have a raw pointer ptrEnd to this area which points right after the last object of the area.
- I have a pointer ptrCurrent that points to some position inside this area.

Now what I want is some kind of wrapper class that helps me insert new elements into this area. It should have some kind of "append" function which basically does the following things

- Assign *ptrCurrent the value of object to insert
- Increment ptrCurrent by one.
- Omit the aforementioned steps if ptrCurrent >= ptrEnd. Return an error instead (or a false to indicate failure).

I could write something like this myself, but I wanted to ask first if there is a class in C++ STL that allows me to solve this problem more elegantly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no "error returning" in the way you want it from a STL class, so I guess you have to write your own one, but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: You probably don't mean [the stl](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/).

Comment: C++ standard library. Whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an AppendHelper class that takes the start and end pointer and otherwise reproduces the std::vector interface. I realized that using std::vector with a custom allocator meant not having full control over when allocation and deallocation is performed, so the result could behave differently from my original intention.

Answer (score 4):

There is a convenient feature for exactly this in C++17, *polymorphic allocators*. More specifically, this is what you want:

```
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource buffer(sizeof(T) * 256);
    // Buffer that can hold 256 objects of type `T`.

std::pmr::vector<T> vec(&buffer);
    // The vector will use `buffer` as the backing storage.
```

[**live godbolt.org example**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tw8gzd)

Comment: I do not have C++17, I have to use C++11. Also, I have no control over the allocation of the buffer, I just have raw pointers I receive from an external library.

Comment: What happens when you push more than that?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov: AFAIK, it's UB.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write an [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) that hands out `T`s from your array, and then `std::vector` can use it.

```
template <typename T>
class ArrayAllocator
{
    T* current;
    T* end;
public:
    using value_type = T;

    ArrayAllocator(T* start, T* end) : current(start), end(end) {}

    T* allocate(size_t n)
    {
         if (current + n >= end) throw std::bad_alloc();
         T * result = current;
         current += n;
         return result;
    }

    void deallocate(T* what, size_t n)
    {
         if (what + n != current) throw std::runtime_error("bad deallocate");
         current = what;
    }

    size_t max_size() { return end - current; }
};
```

You'd have to immediately `reserve` the whole amount, because when `vector` reallocates it needs to copy the old values into the new space, which will result in a "bad deallocate".

Comment: Would it be possible to stop vector from reallocating without using reserve?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to reserve the whole amount